# wikipedia page 100% CPU usage (one-thread, chrome/chromium only (not firefox))

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

This page above has 100% cpu usage in Chrome/Chromium (one thread).

- Can anybody duplicate the above?
- Any web experts able to explain the above?
- Seen on on two x86/AMD64 platforms that I tried. The first is Windows+Nvidia GPU Google-official Chrome and the second is Linux + AMD GPU + ubuntu-snap chromium.
- This does not happen in Firefox on the Linux machine.

I cannot get the exact version information from windows at the moment but it is the 2004 (year 2020) build of Windows 10 Home 64bit and the latest version of Google Chrome.

The Linux version information is below.

Chromium:
Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
I am running a only two extensions: https everywhere, ublock origin.

Firefox (that does not have the problem):
78.0.2 (64-bit)

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-40-generic
Uptime: 3d 20h 51m
Packages: 2785
Shell: bash 5.0.17
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: KDE 5.68.0 / Plasma 5.18.5
WM: KWin

I have tried doing a performance recording, but I did not find the root cause.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference

Comment: Yep, https://crbug.com/1108307

Comment: I'm gertting the same thing on macOS 10.15.5 with chrome 84.0.4147.135. It's not occurring with Firefox. Here is the process path that is running at 100%. `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/84.0.4147.135/Helpers/Google Chrome Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)`

Comment: I just reported this to Chrome